# Neovim LSP with Go

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-go

I am trying to set up my Neovim (nightly - latest) with Go (the programming language).

However, it doesn't seem to be working, most likely because I'm missing something. I'm not sure what though.

Right now, when I open a Go file, at the bottom of Vim, I get a message saying:

> Autostart for gopls failed: matching root directory not detected.

With the Go file still open, if I run `:LspInfo` I get:

[image: screenshot of LspInfo]

**CURRENT CONFIG:**

1. [vimrc](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/.dotfiles/blob/main/.config/nvim/init.vim)
2. [zprofile](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/.dotfiles/blob/main/.config/zsh/.zprofile)
3. [completion.lua](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/.dotfiles/blob/main/.config/nvim/lua/completion.lua) (has `cmp` and `lspconfig`)

What am I missing? Why am I not getting auto-complete, go to definition, find references ...etc (the usual LSP stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, the buffer doesn't get attached unless I have a `.git` folder in the project root directory, or a `go.mod` file.

I didn't have those, I just had a `main.go`.

Comment: appreciate you following up on this! Had the same issue tonight. Cheers!

Comment: You’re welcome :)